# Rails check if has_many exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

Is there a way in rails to check to see if a parents collection is nil in the query? I want to get all the parents that don't have any children. Example:

```
parent_with_no_child = Parent.find(:all, :include => :childs, :conditions => {:childs => :childs.exist?})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Parent.all( :include => :children, :conditions => "children.parent_id IS NULL")
```

I prefer to use counter cache column as shown in this [Railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column) and get the :children_count on Parent model as written by @PeterWong

Answer (score 0):

```
Parent.find(Child.all.collect(&:user_id))
```

Looking forward to seeing better solution. (I remember there is a way to just return some specific columns instead of the full table from Child. But I do not remember the method......)

IMO since parent hasn't child means the parent's id do not exist in child's parent_id, a way to get all ids in child's parent_id would be a must.

BTW, you may consider adding a cache counter `children_count` to parents table, so creating or destroying a child would update it's parent's counter.

In this case, you may just do this: `Parent.where(:children_count => 0)`

However, you will have to make sure the cache counter is correct and consistent, or else the result would not be correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
parent_with_no_child = Parent.find(:all,
  :joins => :childs, 
  :group => 'childs.parent_id HAVING COUNT(child.parent_id) = 0')
```

Or something like that.

Comment: Actually, try using :includes rather than :joins. I'm pretty sure that the INNER JOIN that rails would filter out parents with no child.